# How do I get the contents of a URI that uses the `file` protocol in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

How can I write a function of the type `Text -> IO (Maybe ByteString)` where the argument to `Text` is a URI that uses the `file` protocol, e.g. `file://foo/bar`?

Comment: Is parsing the URI then opening the file out of the question?

Comment: Note that `download` package can directly operate on file protocol: https://github.com/psibi/download

Comment: Check whether the text begins with `file://<rest>` and then load `/<rest>`.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson not at all! If you want to submit that as an answer, though I won't know whether to accept it or Sibi's.

Comment: @Sibi thanks for the tip. If you want to submit that as an answer.

Comment: @Zeta that happens not to be correct, it won't work for non-local files. See the "Non-local files" section here: https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-appsawg-file-scheme-03#appendix-A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want using the package [download](https://www.stackage.org/package/download). But note that the type signature is little different than what you wanted:

```
openURI :: String -> IO (Either String ByteString)
```

The first String parameter denotes url which can be `FTP`, `HTTP` or a file protocol. Note that this package doesn't support `HTTPS` protocol.